# Get number via XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

There's a part of the page:

```
<p>
  349
  <span>
    $
  </span>
</p>
```

How to get "349"?

Comment: The question is, what do you know about this XML? Presumably the 349 could be a different number, otherwise you wouldn't need to look in the XML at all. But what other parts could vary? Will the span element always be there? Will it always contain a "$" sign? Might there be other content in the XML that we need to avoid matching by mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many XPaths that will select `"349"` from that XML.  Here are a few:

- ***Select the space-normalized text node children of `p`:***

  ```
  normalize-space(/p/text())
  ```
- ***Select the space-normalized substring before the `$` in the string value of `p`:***

  ```
  normalize-space(substring-before(/p, '$'))
  ```
- ***Select space-normalized, numeric text nodes anywhere in the document:***

  ```
  normalize-space(//text()[number(.) = .])
  ```

All of these XPaths will select `"349"` as a string as requested.  You could also wrap any of the above expressions with a **`number()`** function call if you actually want `349` as a number rather than as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show the complete page, we don't have a complete path, but try this:

```
 /p/text()
```